# django-corsheaders, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: django, cors, django-cors-headers

Let me appreciate your help in advance.

I deployed FE and BE in different servers on different domains. django-corsheaders is in use in django to deal with CORS, but the response does not include Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
I searched and tested out a lot but nothing worked.

Also, I read this article "https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS"
I understood the logic, so I couldn't get why my case was not working.
The weirdest point is that some requests to specific endpoints return a response with Access-Control-Allow-Origin which makes me confused.

Thank you for your advice.

```
DJANGO settings

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddtriede', //tried to set corsheaders.middleware above here 
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = getenv(
    'CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS',
    'http://localhost:3000,http://127.0.0.1:3000'
).split(',')
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

## **Here is okay case response and request**

**Response**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
"here is FE origin"
Allow:
POST, OPTIONS

Cache-Control:
public, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:
37
Content-Type:
application/json
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy:
same-origin
Date:
Fri, 08 Sep 2023 04:39:17 GMT
Referrer-Policy:
same-origin
Server:
Vercel
Strict-Transport-Security:
max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Vary:
Accept, origin
X-Content-Type-Options:
nosniff
X-Frame-Options:
DENY
X-Vercel-Cache:
MISS
X-Vercel-Id:
syd1::iad1::ssnw2-1694147954133-6c4eee9047a5
```

**Request**

```
:authority:
"here is FE origin"
:method:
POST
:path:
/api/jwt/verify/
:scheme:
https
Accept:
*/*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:
no-cache
Content-Length:
0
Origin:
"here is FE origin"
Pragma:
no-cache
Referer:
"here is FE origin + /"
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
cross-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

## Here is the case error occurred

**Response**

```
Cache-Control:
public, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:
79
Content-Type:
application/json
Date:
Fri, 08 Sep 2023 05:17:07 GMT
Server:
Vercel
Strict-Transport-Security:
max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Vercel-Cache:
MISS
X-Vercel-Error:
FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT
X-Vercel-Id:
syd1::psjt7-1694150227699-15cc280b7c39
```

**Request**

```
:authority:
"here is FE origin + /"
:method:
GET
:path:
/api/o/google-oauth2/?redirect_uri=https://friend-records-nextjs.vercel.app/auth/google
:scheme:
https
Accept:
application/json
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:
no-cache
Origin:
"here is FE origin"
Pragma:
no-cache
Referer:
"here is FE origin + /"
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
cross-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac O
S X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```